# Initialize C++ object with arguments from Cython constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, cython, default-constructor

I have implemented a `filter` class in C++, and I am working on wrapping this with Cython for use in Python. The Cython `MyFilter` class currently looks like this.

```
cdef class MyFilter:
    cdef filter f;
    def __cinit__(self, list array_sizes):
        cdef vector[size_t] as = array_sizes
        self.f.init(as)
    def add(self, uint32_t value):
        self.f.add(value)
    def get(self, uint32_t value):
        return self.f.get(value)
```

Originally, the C++ class had a single constructor which took a `std::vector<size_t>` as an argument. But to make the Cython wrapper work, I had to define a default argument-less constructor and then add an `init()` function to initialize the object once the arguments were available from the `__cinit__` constructor. This added some unwanted complexity to the C++ code.

Is there are cleaner or better way of doing this? I'd like to avoid pointers if necessary, but might be convinced with a compelling argument.

Comment: A move assignment operator might be a bit neater? The overall amount of code needed would be pretty similar but it's a neater C++ interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your solution IS the cleaner better way :)

The other solution is just to add an overloaded constructor, that you can then call from init.:

```
cdef cppclass myclass:
    myclass() except +
    myclass(args) except +
```

Then add to your python class

```
cdef class myPyClass:
    cdef myclass pclass
    def __cinit__(self,args):
        pclass = new myclass(args)
```

Comment: The other solution would be to just have an overloaded constructor.